# Most reliable JSON viewer/editor module for AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I now need to add a feature on the app I'm building a json editor. I would like to know which module have you tried before that you think is stable and worked really well.

The source data is already in json format which I receive from an API call. I already have a button which will call $scope.viewJson() but I'm still missing which json editor module I should use. I saw this today but not sure if there is another few ones that are better - https://github.com/rodikh/angular-json-editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of https://github.com/rodikh/angular-json-editor.

It's basically a directive wrapper for jdorn's [json-editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor). His project is very popular and in active development. Both it, and my wrapper are safe to use.

If you have any feature requests or issues with my wrapper, feel free to submit an issue on github and I'll try my best to resolve them.

Answer (score 3):

#### The best one (to my mind, but anyone is free to disagree my opinion) is `formly`

- [formly site](http://angular-formly.com/#/)
- [formly github](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly)
- [formly documentation](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.4.0/docs/getting-started)

PROS :

- complete (*you can make beautiful and unique forms : templates are some kind like unlimited*)
- well documented
- easy to implement

CONS :

- you have to design your own builder (it is not a problem to my mind)

Comment: I'll check it out. Right now, I'm playing with https://github.com/bastiendonjon/angular-jsoneditor

Comment: This one is really good too. Choose the best that suits to you.

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is old.. but i was looking for this for quite for some time.

and i found this editor 's tutorial: Ace builds
[Ace builds tutorial](https://techincent.com/angular-code-editor/)

i found maximum above editor unmaintained.
you can check its github repo here
[ace build GitHub repo](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/master/src)

i hope it saves someone's time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).